# to_s and to_sym dont work

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

simple as that

```
c = :cat
c.to_s
puts c.class
```

gives me Symbol, and

```
c = "cat"
c.to_sym
puts c.class
```

gives String. Ruby I use is 1.9.3 and documentation says this should convert symbol to string, and string to symbol. What can possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_s` and `to_sym` do not mutate the original variable, but rather return a value. You need to call `.class` in chain with `.to_s`.

```
c = :cat
c.to_s.class
# "String"

c = "cat"
c.to_sym.class
# "Symbol"
```

If you want a new variable converted, you must assign it.

```
c = "cat"
d = c.to_sym
puts d.class
# d is a symbol
# "Symbol"
```

Comment: ok, this works, but does it mean that c.to_s is in fact completely useless?

Comment: @KubaPolaczek No, it means you call it where needed. It's quite useful and I use it all the time. If you need a new variable, assign the value.

Answer (score 2):

`to_s` and `to_sym` return the new value, they don't convert the variable.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
c = :cat
c = c.to_s
puts c.class # "String"

c = "cat"
c = c.to_sym
puts c.class # "Symbol"
```